# Definition of a Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In the book *Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis* written by *Sheldon Axler*, he gave an example of the measure (the next paragraph is a direct quotation):

Suppose $X$ is a set and $S$ is the $\sigma-algebra$ on $X$ consisting of all subsets of $X$
that are either countable or have a countable complement in $X$. Define a measure $\mu:S\to\mathbb{R}$ on $(X,S)$ by $\mu(E)=0$ if $E$ is countable and $\mu(E)=3$ if $E$ is uncountable.

I'm new to measure theory and don't know why we need to define $\mu(E)=3$ here, and I also can't verify why this definition of measure is valid; can someone give me some hint if possible? Thanks in advance.

The definition of measure is in this wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)

Comment: *We* define the measure, so we don’t *need* to choose any specific values; that’s up to us. That is, as long as the function we make is actually a measure in the end, so we need to verify that. Hint: To prove $\sigma$-additivity, use that any collection of disjoint measurable sets can only have at most one uncountable set (why?).

Comment: And to clarify, the values $3$ is completely arbitrary. It could be any value in the extended non-negative reals.

Comment: @Milten Thanks for your answer; in fact why there's at most one uncountable set is exactly what I'm confusing with; I had brief thought that I have to prove the complement of the union of those disjoint sets is also uncountable if there're more than one uncountable set in there, but I don't know how.

Comment: So, according to the definition of $S$, and uncountable $S$-measurable set has a countable complement. So then, how could we possibly have two *disjoint* and ucountable measurable sets? We can't! Because each of them is a subset of the other's complement, so there's not enough room there, so to speak. Think of it like, an uncountable $S$-measurable set fills up almost all of $X$. If $X$ were the real numbers, then a typical example would be $\Bbb R\setminus \{1, 2\}$ or $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Z$. Does that make sense?

Comment: If the countable sets in $S$ are labelled $E_i$ and their complements $E_i^c$ are also in $S$ then the point worth noting is that $E_a^c \cup E_b^c = (E_a \cap E_b)^c$  is also in $S$ since its complement $E_a \cap E_b$ is countable; similarly  $E_a^c \cup E_b = (E_a \cap E_b^c)^c$ is also in $S$ since its complement $E_a \cap E_b^c$ is countable, and you can extend these to countable unions

Comment: @Milten Thanks I got it; the complement of the uncountable set in the $\sigma-algebra$ here should be countable so it can't contain an uncountable set.

Answer (score 2):

Outline: Let $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be disjoint sets belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra, and define $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$. There are two cases:

1. First possibility is each $E_n$ is countable. Then, what can you say about $E$? So, what is $\mu(E)$? What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)$?
2. The other case is there exists some $i\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $E_i$ is uncountable. What can you say about $E_j$ for all $j\neq i$? What can you say about $E$? What is $\mu(E)$? What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)$?